# Site Feed can't be Activated

Tags: 2013, cache

I can't make "Site Feed" activated from Managed Site Features. It says

> An unexpected error has occurred.

I get logs with

> get-splogevent -starttime (get-date).addminutes(-1) | fl message >
>   c:\errors.txt

Here is the error:

> viewstatelog: Failed to write to the velocity cache

**Edited:**

I think I found the solution for this error. I write these commands at Powershell:

```
$instanceName ="SPDistributedCacheService Name=AppFabricCachingService"
$serviceInstance = Get-SPServiceInstance | ? {($_.service.tostring()) -eq $instanceName -and ($_.server.name) -eq $env:computername}
$serviceInstance.Provision()
```

But It says there is no available memory for Provision().

How can I clear cache?

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: Sharepoint 2013

Answer (score 1):

Check out this post which will help you in fixing the error which I have faced before configuring the News Feeds in SharePoint 2013.

[Site Feeds Error in SharePoint 2013](http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.in/2013/08/news-feeds-not-working-in-sharepoint.html)

Comment: Hi @Maruthu and welcome to our site. When you post answers please remember to mention when you promote your own blog. The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, **you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.** Read about expected [behaviour](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). Also remember that "link only answers" is of less use for our site, since links tend to die. Add a good summary of your answer and *then* link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PowerShell cmdlet [Clear-SPDistributedCacheItem](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219715.aspx) to clear your cache.

```
Clear-SPDistributedCacheItem -ContainerType DistributedLogonTokenCache
```